# Requesting NAME OF FORM by php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Requesting  NAME OF FORM by php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047013/requesting-name-of-form-by-php)

I have a form with no captcha and this is submitting by POST method.I am fearing for Spamming. User can spam my database by ajax. How will i protect it by Spammers.ANy idea.. thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have a form with no captcha" - implement a captcha, and/or add a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce).

Comment: This is not the same as the other question. Edit the question or resubmit it. But get rid of the "NAME OF FORM" stuff. Your question is how do you protect against spamming. There are probably lots of questions like that already and the name of the form is not the right direction to go in.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple addition field.

Ask something like:  2 + 3=

And verify that the value is 5 using PHP.

Its a very simplistic captcha, but its better than nothing. Can easily be cracked though.

Comment: +1 for the interesting (but nowadays surprisingly common) solution and the warning.