# PHP: How to get name value in <form name="form1" />

Tags: php, post

Is there a way to get the value of the name attribute in the form tag? I'm using PHP and don't see it in $`_POST`.

Comment: There is not a single reason to get it. Why do you need that?

Comment: You can't think of a reason why one might want to know the name of a form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the form's 'name' variable from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846020/how-to-access-the-forms-name-variable-from-php)

Comment: @YourCommonSense i myself do. When you have several forms pointing to the same action form to call.

Comment: @webs so your question is how to tell one form from another, not "how to get the name attrubute"

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes but it is well answered here and a small test shows the answer is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the value of the name attribute in the form tag? I'm using PHP and don't see it in $_POST.

No, the form's name attribute is never set to sent to the server as part of the POST data.

The easiest way around this would be adding a hidden form element `<input type="hidden">` containing the name.

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="frmname" value=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: No, that's incorrect. At least it's not standard behaviour.

Comment: It doesn't work for me in any major browser. Can you show a test case where this works? Which browsers did you test this with?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="wut">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="wut"/>
</form>
```